# PHP table user ranking due to highest kills

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm fetching data from a MYSQL database I've created which stores a players statistics I.E. kills, deaths, ratio. I have fetched all of the data and made it into a table format in my PHP lines of code but I'd like to know (since im very new to PHP) how I could possibly make it so that the top number of kills go above in the table and the number 'id' changes for every player regarding their rank.

Here are the lines of codes:

```
 echo "<table width='1000' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5' border='1'>"; 
 echo "<tr
<td><center><b>RANK</td></center></b><td><b><center>Nickname</td></center></b><td><center><b>Kills</td></center></b><td><center><b>     Deaths</td></center></b><td><center><b>Ratio</td></center></b></tr>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo "<tr> 
    <td><center><b>".$info['id']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['username']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['kills']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['deaths']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['ratio']."</td></center></b></tr>"; 

 } 
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY kill DESC` in your MySQL query to order the rows by kill rate. Also, `<center>` is obsolete, you should be using CSS styles for this.

Comment: In addition the tags aren't well-formed (it should be nested properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append an `order by kills desc` to your SQL statement so the max kills is first.